# How can I remove a single character given from a file in scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a txt file "blah.txt" which reads

```
word 3 + 6
```

Now consider the following code:

```
(define c (read-char file))
(define (toke c)
        (cond
         ((null? c)(write "empty"))

        ((equal? (read-char c) #\space)(write 'space)
         ;           (toke (with the next character)
         )
         ((equal? (read-char c) #\+) (write '+)
          ;              (toke (with the next character)
         )
        ((equal? (read-char c) #\-) (write '-)
          ;               (toke (with the next character)
         )
         ((equal? (read-char c) #\*) (write '*)
          ;               (toke (with the next character)
         )
         ((equal? (read-char c) #\/) (write '/)
          ;               (toke (with the next character)
         )
         ((equal? (read-char c) #\=) (write '=)
          ;               (toke (with the next character)
           )           
         ((equal? (read-char c) #\() (write 'LPAREN)
            ;             (toke (with the next character)
         )
         ((equal? (read-char c) #\)) (write 'RPAREN)
          ;               (toke (with the next character)
         )
         ((char-numeric? (read-char c)) (write 'Num)
          ;                  (toke (with the next character)
         )

         ((char-alphabetic? (read-char c))(write 'ID)
          ;                    (toke (with the next character)
         )
         (else
          (write "error"))))
```

I'm not looking to output to a text file. I simply want to be able to move on to the next character. 
I've had unsuccessful attempts at solving it.
Also for some reason I keep getting errors with char-numeric? and char-alphabetic? telling me that I have given it the eof instead of a what it expects when I save my file as 
3 a + r (for example)

I know it involves changing it into a string but I keep getting a string of "word 3 + 6" for which I cannot do (car).
let me explain that a little further
I know you can do 
(define list
file->list "blah.txt")
which will contain '(word 3 + 4)
but then doing 
(define str
file->string "blah.txt") 
it will contain "word 3 + 4"
and I cannot do (car str) to get "word" out because the whole (car) is "word 3 + 4"
Please forgive me if I can't explain myself correctly as I am new to scheme

Comment: @ColeJohnson Racket (Scheme), it's in the tags.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez i've never heard of it. so i didn't know

Comment: Being Lindsay Lohan didn't help much on Stack Overflow, did it? :)

Comment: @OscarLopez Haha! you should add that as an answer to see how many upvotes you get

Answer (score 1):

Read the contents of the file using `(file->lines "blah.txt")`, that will return a list, with each line of the file as a string in the list.

After that, it'll be simple to manipulate each line; for instance using the procedure `string->list` (see the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html)) to convert a line to a list of characters and iterating over each of the characters by `cdr`-ing over the list.

Comment: Oscar, I see what you're telling me to do but I can't get it to work.

Comment: The same questions have been asked over and over again in the last couple of days, by you or your classmates. Click on the `scheme` tag and take a look at the answers, it's all there, really, you just need to put a little effort on your part.

Answer (score 1):

Racket (and more generally, Scheme) provides a *port* datatype that allows you to get sequential access to a file or stream.  You can *peek* and *read* individual bytes from it.

There's some reference Racket documentation here: [Byte and String input](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Byte_and_String_Input.html).

As an example of such a scanner, you can look at [Section 6](http://hashcollision.org/brainfudge/#%28part._.Parsing_the_surface_syntax%29) of my mini-tutorial on making a Racket-based language.

Note that a string is not itself a port, but we can create a port whose source comes from a string.  Racket provides an `open-input-string` function to turn strings into input ports.  So you should be able to do something like this:

```
#lang racket
(define myport (open-input-string "hello"))

(printf "I see: ~s\n" (read-char myport))
(printf "I see: ~s\n" (read-char myport))
(printf "I see: ~s\n" (read-char myport))
(printf "I see: ~s\n" (read-char myport))
(printf "I see: ~s\n" (read-char myport))
```

to see the individual characters coming out.  Change `read-char` to `peek-char` and you'll see that `peek-char` does not take the data out of the port, but allows you to *peek* into it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading a little on how to implement scanners in Scheme.
Eric Hilsdale and Christopher T. Haynes has written some very nice notes.

First the scanner:
http://www.cs.indiana.edu/eip/compile/scanparse.html

Then the big picture:
http://www.cs.indiana.edu/eip/compile/